# XML Serialization class is inaccesible due to its protection level and ILRepack

Tags: c#, xml, ilrepack

I am getting the following error:

> is inaccessible due to its protection level. Only public types can be
>   processed. at System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()

on a model class that I am using for deserializing XML. I only get this when I merge my assemblies using `ILRepack`. If I do not merge the assemblies or exclude the assembly containing the model class it works.

Comment: You are trying to serialize a class property that is not PUBLIC just like the error message indicates.  Class properties must be public to use serialization.

Comment: The class and all the properties are public. The program works until I merge the assemblies into one executable with ILRepack. If I exclude the assembly containing the class from ILRepack and leave it as a standalone dll it also works.

Comment: The webpage says following : Fixed internal method overriding public one which isn't allowed in the same assembly (Simon).  See https://github.com/gluck/il-repack

Comment: @jdweng that last comment got me in the right direction. I needed to add that assembly to the internalizeExclude group in my ILRepack.targets file. Thank you.